# Generate a random date on specific year

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can i generate a random date with the year "1900" in PL/SQL ?

For example, i want to generate in a variabile called date_random, dates that contain the year 1900 .

I tried in many ways (DATEADD,DATEDIFF) but can't get to the result. Some help, please ?

Comment: No suggestions from https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pl%2Fsql+random+date ?

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
DECLARE
   l_date   DATE;
BEGIN
   l_date := TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + 
             ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 365));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_date);

   /* And for a specific year */
   l_date := TRUNC (DATE '1900-01-01', 'YYYY') + 
             ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 365));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_date);
END;
/
```

The DBMS_RANDOM comes in really handy!

Comment: Great solution! Of course, if you want to allow Jan 1 to be a possibility, your low value would need to be 0 instead of 1. But that will depend on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work?

```
declare @FromDate date = '1900-01-01'
declare @ToDate date = '1900-12-31'

select dateadd(day, 
           rand(checksum(newid()))*(1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)), 
           @FromDate)
```

Or perhaps something more like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365), '1900-01-01')
FROM your_table
```

This generates dates starting from `1900-01-01`, and you can change the amount of days in the modulus value, I put `365` (1 year), this approach doesn't overflow.

Comment: I understand the idea, but i want to maintan this random date into a variable. For example, DECLARE date_random DATE. I don't succeed, to make it in a variable.

Comment: Isn't this T-SQL? The question was flagged for Oracle's PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try too. Pure SQL tweak . Hope this helps.

```
SELECT TRUNC(to_date('01/01/'
  ||'&enter_year','mm/dd/yyyy'),'month')+ROUND(dbms_random.value(1,
  CASE
    WHEN mod('&enter_year',4) = 0
    THEN 366
    ELSE 365
  END)) days
FROM dual;
```